# Python 3.10 / Open CV 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: numpy

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
while(True);
    ret, frame = cap.read()
            
    output = frame.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)
    
    gray = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,3.5)
    
    kernel = np.ones((2.6,2.7),np.uint8)
    gray = cv2.erode(gray,kernel,iterations = 1)
    
    gray = cv2.dilate(gray,kernel,iterations = 1)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 260, param1=30, param2=65, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
        

        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
            cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)
            #time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Column Number: ")
            print(x)
            print("Row Number: ")
            print(y)
            print("Radius is: ")
            print(r)

            cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
            cv2.imshow('frame',output)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

kernel = np.ones((2.6,2.7),np.uint8)

Exception has occurred: TypeError

'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Unfortunately I can't run this script. It must have something to do with recent Python or opencv changes.

Comment: By the documentation of numpy.ones, the first argument represents the size of the array.
You are requesting an array of size 2.6 by 2.7 which is obviously not a valid dimension.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html

Comment: I replaced 2.6/2.7 with 2/1 but got a new problem on line 22: output = frame.copy()

Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'

What I am really looking for is a working circle detection in real time example, I already spent half a day looking for one

Comment: You should add an else clause:
`if frame is None`, you cannot call `copy` on it. That's what the error message says. It seems that you are aware that `frame` can be `None` as you have an `if` clause to catch these.

Answer (score 0):

This line causes the issue

```
kernel = np.ones((2.6,2.7),np.uint8)
```

Your `np.ones` expects to give a shape like (2,2) so that it will create an np array full of ones with the shape (2,2) instead you are passing (2.6,2.7) which cannot be a shape. Shape consists of integers while 2.6 and 2.7 are float numbers